# Xcode Swift binary data showing in email instead of image

Tags: html, ios, swift3, binary-data, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm producing an IOS App that has the ability to send an email from within it. Within the email methods I'm using the following:

```
let imageString = returnEmailStringBase64EncodedImage(image: ImageView.image!)
 let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
 mail.mailComposeDelegate = self as MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
 mail.setToRecipients([KBEmail.text!])
 mail.setSubject("SBSS Knowledgebase Record: " + KBTitle.text!)



func returnEmailStringBase64EncodedImage(image:UIImage) -> String {
        let imgData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData;
        let dataString = imgData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        return dataString
    }
```

and within the HTML string I'm adding:

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,\(imageString)'>
```

When sending an email to myself, I get the same email on my MacBook Pro, iPad and iPhone 6. On the iPad and iPhone the email displays exactly the way I want it. On the Mac and Android devices it's showing the HTML and encoded string like so:

```
--Apple-Mail-4012341F-CA6F-4B5E-A556-2AF6b4AFCC0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head><meta http-equiv=3D"content-type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3D=
utf-8"></head><body dir=3D"auto"><div><table><tbody><tr><td style=3D"font-fa=
mily: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #000080; text-=
align: center;">Puffer with the fluid Giz gave me</td></tr><tr><td><hr style=
=3D"width:100%"></td></tr><tr><td style=3D"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sa=
ns-serif; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; text-align: center; color=
: #000080;">I think =F0=9F=A4=94 it=E2=80=99s about 6% nicotine </td></tr><t=
r><td style=3D"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;=
color: #000080; text-align: center;"><hr style=3D"width:100%"><img src=3D"d=
ata:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARcAAADRCAYAAADmFfbJAAAAAXNSR0I=
Ars4c6QAAABxpRE9UAAAAAgAAAAAAAABpAAAAKAAAAGkAAABoAAEma2igPnYAAEAASURBVHgBnL0=
Hd1VXlrbbf+Le7+uu7rJdDkQlkIRIIgiJnEFESSjnnCWEAgJElEBC5JxMzsk2yQabnJ1zrirbZVd=
wBZft9z5z7XMkcNft8d3rMabX3vtkcfaz3/nOudb5t5//8FD++OmbB7L48ev7vrirN+9e06rWTaq=
av15VjRtVvWgrsV3Vi3eqdsU+zW89oobWo2pcc0qLN76kJZvOaenmC1q86bya2J+/9rRqVx1X5bK=
DKl64R/kNO5RVs1mZNZtUvGCnkktWKWZSlvoOm6k+Q6ao94CxCuwzQl2DB6tLYKSeCx6ibsFD1TN
```

Has anyone had anything similar or can tell me why this is happening?

I don't have the privileges on this site to upload images, sorry, so I can't show any screen dumps.

UPDATE:
Replaced the returnEmailStringBase64EncodedImage function with:

```
func encodeImageToBase64(image : UIImage) -> String{
        let imageData : Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as Data
        let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
        return strBase64
    }
```

and the emails show OK on the MacBook, iPhone and iPad. When using Safari and Gmail the email looks OK but the image isn't showing. Getting there slowly :)

Comment: This is even weirder!!! If I forward the email from my MacBook, where it's showing the encoded string, to myself and pick that email up on my iPhone or iPad, the email looks perfectly OK. The image is showing and no encoded string.